# Just installed ubuntu and my wireless is not working

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, kernel, intel

Hey I just installed ubuntu and my wireless is not working.  It is a intel dual band wireless ac 3165.  My first thought was to go to the intel and get the driver for it.  So I done that and got the right kernel version for it.  I extracted it and in the folder it just .ucode files what am I meant to do with them?

Thank you

Alex

EDIT:  uname -a info.

```
Linux AlexSchezar 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:24:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 81)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4010]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8093]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Kernel is 3.19.0-49-generic and I downloaded this file.  http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html

It's the one named Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 (starting from firmware XX.XX.13.0 and kernel 4.1) that I downloaded.

Comment: What is the kernel version and what file did you download?

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/732002/edit) to include results for `uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: 3.19.0-49-generic and I downloaded this file.  http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html.  Its the first one, it's named Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? If it is 14.04. run `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily and reboot`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue on my HP Envy laptop which has Intel 3165 wifi adaptor card. I tried many work around involving getting the firmware from the git repository also. It helped me for some time but my wifi connection used to go away after 1-2 hours. Finally I looked into Intel's website and they also had mentioned that Kernel 4.1+ is certified for 3165. I finally upgraded the kernel and my wifi works very well. I was using Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS.
Here is the final link for my [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723446/wifi-issue-should-i-upgrade-the-kernel)
Hope this helps.