# Best way to upgrade kernel in Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: kernel

Due to my wifi issue as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723446/wifi-issue-should-i-upgrade-the-kernel) I have to upgrade my kernel to 4.2.x
following these commands:

```
$ cd /tmp  
$ wget \  kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2.5-wily/linux-headers-4.2.5-040205_4.2.5-040205.201510270124_all.deb \  kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2.5-wily/linux-headers-4.2.5-040205-generic_4.2.5-040205.201510270124_amd64.deb \  kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2.5-wily/linux-image-4.2.5-040205-generic_4.2.5-040205.201510270124_amd64.deb  
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.2*.deb linux-image-4.2*.deb
```

And i know i can remove that using:

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.2* linux-image-4.2*
```

This has fixed my wifi driver(Intel wifi 3165) issue. But I learnt that i got the kernel from mainline and it's not a very good idea as I won't be getting any more updates etc...
So what's the right way of upgrading the kernel?
I heard that i should be using:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Want to know what exactly i need to do to upgrade kernel properly? For me it's very important as if i don't have this kernel version my wifi doesn't work. Moreover want to know what will happen to my Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS with this upgraded kernel when the new LTS version(16.04 LTS) comes in during April, 2016?

I have another constraint:
I need to be on LTS release as some of the software tools/products(DSE and RLEC) that i use - requires 14.04.3 LTS release only. That's why cannot go to 15.10

Comment: Sincerely, the best option is to install 15.10 for now and do a fresh install when 16.04 is released. Messing with kernels is always risky.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/08/upgrade-kernel-4-2-ubuntu/

Comment: @EduardoCola. Forgot to mention in the original question - I need to be on LTS release as some of the software tools/products that i use - requires 14.04.3 LTS release only. That's why cannot go to 15.10

Comment: If you install the Wily LTS kernel version you can always fallback to an older version, so you could give it a try and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing from Ubuntu repositories is preferred.

This will install a supported Ubuntu kernel and it will get updates.

If you install a mainline kernel, you may have issues with some drivers, and you will have to update it manually.

Ubuntu kernel 4.2 will be default in the next "point" LTS release 14.04.4 that is scheduled to be out in Feb 2016.

There should be no problems in upgrading to 16.04.

Installing `linux-generic-lts-wily` now you install that kernel a bit earlier than it will be released for all LTS new installs.

You can read more about [HWE Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Comment: Thanks.How i will be upgrading to 16.04 LTS? is lts-wily same as 4.2? Where is the mapping mentioned? I can see that 15.10 and 16.04 should be having the kernel 4.2(does it comes by default or it simply means that it supports kernel version 4.2). As the rule of thumb-don't fix unless it is broken...may be it's a good idea for me to wait for 16.04 and then upgrade at that time.

Comment: You upgrade a normal way. People who will install 14.04 after 14.04.4 is released will have it already. 15.10 has kernel 4.2. 16.04 will have probably 4.4. It is your choice, but standard kernels with updates are a bit better way than what you did.

Comment: tried this command  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily" got the kernel 4.2.x - generic...but getting into the login loop after that.

Comment: I never recommended that command. Where do you see it in my answer? It is wrong.

Comment: that 'HWE Stack' https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack has that command

Comment: But that is a wrong command.

Comment: what is wrong with that command - i am able to install linux generic kernel 4.2.0.x following that...after that there was black screen kind of issue...i am trying to apt-get nvidia-358 to make it work

Comment: This is a long story to answer in comments.