# Upgraded to kernel 4.2 but getting black screen after that

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, upgrade, kernel

I had a mainline kernel 4.2.5 and based on the advise that i should not have a baseline kernel as in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735469/best-way-to-upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu-desktop-14-04-3-lts/735472?noredirect=1#comment1096310_735472) I installed it via this command

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-core-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-wily xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-wily libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-wily
```

but after that i keep on getting black screen. I thought it's because of my nvidia driver so i referred my earlier [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop)

and then executed

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot


sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

But i am still having black screen.
Even if i do

> Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key. Add
>   nouveau.modeset=0 to the end of the linux line. Press F10 to boot the
>   Ubuntu operating system

### I get black screen only.

Had a chat with Pilot6
execute this command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libglapi-mesa-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386

lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

tells that nvidia kernel is in use

Later i purged nvidia and install it

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime 
sudo reboot
```

But even after that I am having black screen only. I need to login into Recovery mode and then normal boot and then Ctrl+Alt+F1 to do any work.

==============================================================================
Very unstable system - it was working for around 10-15 minutes then mouse and keyboard - everything is un responsive.

I curse my self - why i tried to do mess up something which was working alright. **Even if that was mainline kernel it was working fine.**

Comment: And your graphics card is .... and you installed all that stuff because .... and you checked the nvidia site for compatibility ....and you are using a mainline kernel because ....

Comment: mainline kernels are provided as is and are not supported "These kernels are not supported and are not appropriate for production use." - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because custom kernels are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve this issue only after doing a clean install of Ubuntu desktop 15.10(not upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 15.10). Had a lot of issues with the  14.04.3 LTS as my wifi was not working and without wifi it is almost impossible to work. Moreover with the mainline kernel being installed and then getting it using standard way further messed up the entire situation. Even when i got the generic kernel 4.2 -i got issues with my nvidia graphics card. Can't devote more than 8 hours on any such things so finally i decided to upgrade to 15.10 and install the required apps. Another reason for doing this upgrade was that it's easy to upgrade to 16.04 LTS once it comes(21st April, 2016). I had backed up all my important data so there was no issue regarding that.
Thanks everyone for your help.

**Moral of the story - don't fix unless it is broken.**

Answer (score 0):

That command is wrong in many cases. Maybe it will work on a fresh installed system. But when you have multiarch 32-bit packages, it removes lots of packages. You could see it when you ran the command.

The correct command is

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libglapi-mesa-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386
```

I ran it on two computers today and upgraded without any issues.

Another unlikely problem may be because you have an unsupported Nvidia driver 361. It may be incompatible with the new version of `xorg-server`.

But as I said, it is very unlikely.

You can fix your system by running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

if you are lucky enough.

P.S. And I never advised you to install new `xorg-server`. I gave you a command to upgrade only the kernel that was

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Upgrading HWE graphical stack from `vivid` to `wily` is not worth the effort, because it is a very minor version change from `1.17.1` to `1.17.2`.

Comment: What this command'sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libglapi-mesa-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386' does? why i386 - mine is 64 bit?

Comment: If you had a 32-bit system, then you would not need `i386` packages. But you probably have 32-bit applications, like Skype or wine` installed. That's why you need 32-bit packages too.

Comment: i don't have either wine or skype

Comment: It is hard to guess what you have. But when you ran that command you should have read what it installed and what REMOVED. Mine command does not remove anything wrong in all cases.

Comment: executed this command 'sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily xserver-xorg-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily libglapi-mesa-lts-wily libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-wily:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-wily:i386'. there was no need to execute 'sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop' and 'sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily' as it's already there...rebooted the system...but still the black screen.

Comment: Enter console and look if nvidia is still installed. `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36090/discussion-between-ashu-and-pilot6).