# Login Loop on Ubuntu 14.04 after latest update

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates, login

It would appear I'm not the only one but I haven't seen any answers on similar posts that work. Wondering if anyone knows the issue. Latest kernel 79. Tried reinstalling lightdm and tried gdm, no luck. Plenty of space so not the issue.

All login attempts has me back at the login screen on any user. Any help would be great. Thanks.

If I upgrade to 15.04 from 14.04, could that perhaps fix the problem? Hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

It could be porblem with .Xauthority i.e x-org.Log in using terminal(Ctrl+Alt+F3 from login screen) and then change permission of your home .Xauthority 
`chown username:username .Xauthority`

Answer (score 0):

There could lot of reasons for login loop. During last 6-8 months i have experienced it when i did something wrong. Undoing that operation or fixing the root cause fixes the login loop most of the time. One such login loop issue is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721633/nvidia-graphics-card-driver-installed-led-to-login-loop)

which was due to nvidia driver issue. I have provided details in terms of how to fix it.

May be you can recollect and undo the actions which has caused this to fix it. Better to do `Ctrl+Alt+F1(F1 to F6)` and go to terminal and try looking under /var/log directory to find out what is causing it.

If it is a fairly new ubuntu install may be you can try 14.04 LTS or stable release all over again(new install) to fix it. Some times that's the best choice also.

In my other [machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737828/upgraded-to-kernel-4-2-but-getting-black-screen-after-that) - i fixed it with reinstall only

Comment: I did remember that the latest install did update graphics driver amd catalyst. There was a few files in which it asked if I wanted to keep or remove. I removed the first and kept the remaining. Perhaps that was it.

Comment: I am still a bit of a noob when it comes to playing around in terminal. How do I read a file in a directory?  I.e. log file - ubuntu-amd-cayalyst-install.log

Comment: cd /var/log/somefile.log and then vi somefile.log. You can go thru some basic linux/ubuntu tutorials before trying out all that.

Comment: I'm not sure which log file would tell me what is going on. What should I look for?