# liveUSB doesn't detect my intel wifi device. Can't enable wifi

Tags: wireless, live-usb, live-cd

I've been trying to install ubuntu on my new computer, HP Envy x360 m6-w102dx but in this computer, the wifi seems to be not recognized. I've been trying to enable it but as shown in `dmesg | grep iwl`, I noticed this error

```
iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-15/14.uc oder failed with error -2
```

Seems like a Intel (R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265 wlan card, but can't see it in rfkill list at all.

Please help me. I would like to install ubuntu on my computer but can't seem to fix the wifi problem.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [link](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html). As per that Intel certifies Linux kernel 4.2 onwards for that wifi card.

I had Intel 3165 and struggled a lot with Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS. Finally i decided to fresh install Ubuntu 15.10 and that fixed the problem. Same i will suggest for you - it will save time and efforts.

You can refer to my thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723446/wifi-issue-should-i-upgrade-the-kernel)

I could only fix it by installing Ubuntu 15.10 which comes with Kernel 4.1/4.2. With the upgraded kernel in Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS i used to get some what intermittent connection issues with the work around suggested in that thread.

When you are installing Ubuntu 15.10 - i will suggest connect your laptop via Ethernet cable. Once everything is installed then you can test your wifi card also. It should work.

Comment: Installed ubuntu 15.10, wifi card still doesnt work... I don't know if the others will work but lets see if it does.

Comment: Still doesn't work.