# Update Wireless Adapter Intel 7260

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, intel-wireless

I am trying to upgrade the wireless card in my Toshiba Portege from an Intel Centrino N2230 to an Intel 7260 card, but currently it is not working. My OS version is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and here are some further details:

```
uname -a
Linux portege-R935 3.13.0-79-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:27:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


lshw
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: wlan1
                version: 73
                serial: 7c:5c:f8:8f:77:cb
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-79-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 ip=192.168.0.187 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
                resources: irq:44 memory:e2400000-e2401fff


ifconfig
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:5c:f8:8f:77:cb  
          inet addr:192.168.0.187  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7e5c:f8ff:fe8f:77cb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1066 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:112810 (112.8 KB)  TX bytes:94922 (94.9 KB)
```

I have so far attempted to download, extract, and copy the firmware into /lib/firmware as described in the last solution to this post: [No wireless for Intel Corporation 7260 version 63](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331667/no-wireless-for-intel-corporation-7260-version-63)

Edit: log output from dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    1.956246] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.063946] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.095594] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    2.095702] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    2.102396] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    2.303181] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.013116] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    4.013442] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    8.212226] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[    8.413151] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[    8.413485] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    8.413929] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    8.520370] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    8.520739] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   11.570269] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   13.174563] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[   13.176011] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   13.176577] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   45.630564] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Time Event end notification failure
[  133.945920] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[  136.339636] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[  137.741875] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[  137.748602] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [link](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html). As per that Intel certifies Linux kernel 4.2 onwards for that wifi card. As per your logs you are still on linux kernel 3.13 which is not certified by Intel and may not work even after work around that you are trying to do.

So my advice is to upgrade to Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 which has Linux kernel 4.2 and it will work.

I had Intel 3165 and struggled a lot with Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS. Finally i decided to fresh install Ubuntu 15.10 and that fixed the problem. Same i will suggest for you - it will save time and efforts.

You can refer to my thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723446/wifi-issue-should-i-upgrade-the-kernel)

I could only fix it by installing Ubuntu 15.10 which comes with Kernel 4.1/4.2. With the upgraded kernel in Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS i used to get some what intermittent connection issues with the work around suggested in that thread.

When you are installing Ubuntu 15.10 - i will suggest connect your laptop via Ethernet cable. Once everything is installed then you can test your wifi card also. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try newer firmware. With a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cd iwlwifi-firmware/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7260*  /lib/firmware
```

Reboot and see if the wireless is now working.

Comment: I gave this a shot and it didn't seem to work. From Ashu's response it sounds like I may have to update to 15.10

Comment: Before you give up, are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: I'm not really sure how to interpret it but I added the output in an edit above

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong and therefor fixable. I suggest you try the live DVD session for 15.10 and be certain your wireless works as expected. I am quite confident it will; it works fine for my 7260!

Comment: @chili555 Upgraded to 15.10, updated the firmware... still no good. Seems like it tries to connect, but never actually does.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `sudo iwlist scan` Trim away all but your own SSID (router).