# Connecting Wireless on Ubuntu 15.10 (Intel AC 7260)

Tags: networking, wireless, intel, iwlwifi

I have been fighting with this for some time, and have no idea how to fix it. I've read the [numerous other posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660155/wifi-losing-connection-weak-signal-intel-7260-adapter) on this topic but none of the solutions have helped me.

So here's the short version of my problem: I can scan for networks but cannot connect.

I have gotten it to connect before, but the signal strength was very weak. Once I moved my machine further from the router (<3 ft) I can no longer connect at all.

Here's the output of the wireless script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 12 Mar 2016 18:16 CST -0600

Booted last: 12 Mar 2016 18:14 CST -0600

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-51-generic #58~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 22:02:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V [8086:15a1]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:85c4]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1532:0502 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b38:0010 Gear Head 107-Key Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

eeepc_wmi              16384  0 
asus_wmi               24576  1 eeepc_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  0 
iwlmvm                278528  0 
mac80211              712704  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               192512  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              524288  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
video                  20480  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface em1 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "Ministry of Magic"
    wpa-psk 709e6f754d96bfdaec99faa1ead659a13843c7f3a26e68f517a40ae7631fa00b 

##### ifconfig ##########################

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'docker0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'docker0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:472437 (472.4 KB)  TX bytes:24829178 (24.8 MB)

em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'em1' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.2.8  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'em1' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8782 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:25358404 (25.3 MB)  TX bytes:678218 (678.2 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7200000-f7220000 

veth19afb3d Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'veth19afb3d' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'veth19afb3d' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3808 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:259348 (259.3 KB)  TX bytes:11511336 (11.5 MB)

veth8beecb5 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'veth8beecb5' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'veth8beecb5' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2643 (2.6 KB)  TX bytes:29363 (29.3 KB)

vethf278c02 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'vethf278c02' [IF]>  
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'vethf278c02' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:328690 (328.6 KB)  TX bytes:13343754 (13.3 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

veth8beecb5  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

veth19afb3d  no wireless extensions.

vethf278c02  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

em1       no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 em1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root      3646     1  0 18:16 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

- Device: em1  [Ifupdown (em1)] ------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'em1' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.2.8
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.2.1

    DNS:             192.168.2.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Foobar]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Foobar | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Foobar | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ministry of Magic]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ministry of Magic | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Ministry of Magic | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

veth8beecb5  no frequency information.

docker0   no frequency information.

veth19afb3d  no frequency information.

vethf278c02  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

em1       no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

veth8beecb5  Interface doesn't support scanning.

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

veth19afb3d  Interface doesn't support scanning.

vethf278c02  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

em1       Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'NETGEAR02-arlo_247004' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=31/70  Signal level=-79 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETGEAR02-arlo_247004"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000100cb753a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3212ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'AT<MAC address>T' [AC2]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"AT&T"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000016997b981c7
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3088ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     4375FD8600770B0C2A7E11D
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:D6:4E:73:6E:B3:B1:A2:3E:2E:4A:9E:A9:B2:F2:73:99:A4:1C:AF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-51-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     1261743510839D352D1D895
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:D6:4E:73:6E:B3:B1:A2:3E:2E:4A:9E:A9:B2:F2:73:99:A4:1C:AF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-10.ucode
srcversion:     B470AF663F8CCFC606AA966
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:D6:4E:73:6E:B3:B1:A2:3E:2E:4A:9E:A9:B2:F2:73:99:A4:1C:AF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-51-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     EF182B558008C23DD85EF03
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E0:D6:4E:73:6E:B3:B1:A2:3E:2E:4A:9E:A9:B2:F2:73:99:A4:1C:AF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 1
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 1
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b1 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    3.928280] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.965705] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times)
[    3.980997] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    7.376255] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[    7.376259] wlan0: AP advertised VHT without HT, disabling both
[    7.378824] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[    7.582464] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address> (try 2/3)
[    7.786635] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address> (try 3/3)
[    7.989767] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address> timed out
[  179.216032] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): em1: link is not ready
[  181.927885] e1000e: em1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[  181.927915] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): em1: link becomes ready
[  233.979635] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
[  234.076729] device veth8beecb5 entered promiscuous mode
[  234.076789] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth8beecb5: link is not ready
[  234.076792] docker0: port 1(veth8beecb5) entered forwarding state (repeated 2 times)
[  234.077086] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): docker0: link becomes ready
[  234.077613] device vethf278c02 entered promiscuous mode
[  234.077669] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethf278c02: link is not ready
[  234.077672] docker0: port 2(vethf278c02) entered forwarding state (repeated 2 times)
[  234.148660] eth0: renamed from vethcd3ad11
[  234.173934] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth8beecb5: link becomes ready
[  234.202216] device veth19afb3d entered promiscuous mode
[  234.202387] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth19afb3d: link is not ready
[  234.202391] docker0: port 3(veth19afb3d) entered forwarding state (repeated 2 times)
[  234.349063] eth0: renamed from veth58d4259
[  234.360693] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth19afb3d: link becomes ready
[  234.924870] docker0: port 2(vethf278c02) entered disabled state
[  234.958503] eth0: renamed from veth3911140
[  234.973242] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethf278c02: link becomes ready
[  234.973277] docker0: port 2(vethf278c02) entered forwarding state (repeated 2 times)
[  249.115836] docker0: port 1(veth8beecb5) entered forwarding state
[  249.243874] docker0: port 3(veth19afb3d) entered forwarding state
[  250.012136] docker0: port 2(vethf278c02) entered forwarding state

########## wireless info END ############
```

I have already tried the various incantations of `options` in `/etc/modprobe/iwlwifi.conf` and they don't really seem to help. Currently this file looks like:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**
I went ahead and updated to 15.10 to see if a newer kernel would help things. The card still behaves the same.

Per a suggestion on [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2317043&p=13454475), I went ahead and tried the backported firmware (17), as it was supposed to improve reliability with this card. Again no improvement...

Comment: Check to see if the antenna(s) are still connected, those cards have better range than that

Comment: @Jeremy31 How would I go about checking that?

Comment: What model is it?  A google search might find out, some laptops are very simple and others require a lot of work

Comment: It's a desktop, so I can get to the physical card pretty easily. Just not sure how to check the antennas.

Comment: In that case, there should be antennas connected to the back of the card http://www.quietpc.com/images/products/int-7260hmwdtx1-wifi-card-large.jpg shows the back of the card with the antenna connectors sticking out, hopefully your connectors have something attached

Comment: @jeremy31 - Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had assumed that this card would work as is, and wasn't aware that I would need an antenna. I tested it out by building a makeshift antenna with some wiring, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [link](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) Intel certifies kernel 4.2 for this wifi card.
Yes there are work arounds that one can try but that might help temporarily. Please refer to my [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723446/wifi-issue-should-i-upgrade-the-kernel).

I had Intel AC 3165 and i tried to make it work on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS with the workaround...some amount of success but connection used to drop every 10-15 minutes.

Finally i upgraded to Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 which comes with kernel 4.2.x and it's working fine after that.

Selectively you can just upgrade your kernel to 4.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS also. But you need to have work around for other apps. 
I believe upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 is worth trying as it's easy to upgrade to 16.04 LTS coming in next month.

**Some debugging tips**

There is some good amount of information available in this forum for debugging the isssue:
Go thru this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and run the [wireless script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info)

Comment: Is there an easy way to upgrade directly from 14.04?

Comment: Try 'sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily'

Comment: Upgraded to 15.10, and still can't connect to any networks...

Comment: @Louis. For me upgrade to 15.10 worked without any issues...can you try the newly edited answer(debugging tips). The same tip has worked for other user(http://askubuntu.com/questions/745324/how-to-get-the-intel-3165-wireless-adapter-to-work-in-ubuntu-14-04/745327?noredirect=1#comment1109671_745327) though in his case it's 3165 NOT 7260.

Comment: Yup tried some of the tips. Nothing seems to work. Upgraded the firmware as proposed by a few others. Didn't seem to help either.

Comment: @Louis. Do you other O/S(Windows)-is this wireless card working in Windows?

Comment: Nope, I have no other machines I can test the card on. Only Linux - I have no Windows machines.