# How to get the intel 3165 wireless adapter to work in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, kernel, intel-wireless

I understand the 4.2 kernel supports this wireless adapter. But I need to stay in Ubuntu 14.04 for my own purposes, and so I need to make it work in here. All other solutions I've seen are for qualcomm adapters or recommend going to the 4.2 kernel.

Current kernel:

`$ uname -r`

`3.19.0-25-generic`

Driving me insane.

Comment: You could copy the driver code from 4.2 and recompile it with your kernel . I am not an expert in this field .. Just pitching an idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to upgrade to kernel 4.2

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

This way you will remain with lsb_release of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but kernel is upgraded. You can verify your Ubuntu release using this

```
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: So if I'm trying to run a script designed for 14.04, will it still run on a machine with a kernel designed for 15.10?

Comment: Yes this script will get the kernel 4.2 on your Ubuntu Desktop 14.04. It will also do a grub-update which will give you a choice whether you want to go to boot 14.04 using kernel 3.x or kernel 4.2. But please backup your important data. So in case something goes wrong...you can always boot to kernel 3.x and purge the new kernel(4.2) is needed.

Comment: @Ashu I suspect he will need the firmware, too. I suggest you add that to your answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. Solved my issue. I'll just run the script from the 3.19 kernel and then switch back to the 4.2 one for wireless access. But my intel 3165 wireless adapter now works perfectly from the 4.2 kernel.

Comment: @AndresArana. Glad to know it worked...please accept the answer by clicking 'tick mark' against it.

Comment: @chili555. Good point. But in my case it worked without the need of firmware. I believe kernel modules already contains that. It worked for OP anyway without any further issues.