# Intel Wireless AC3165 is disabled under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Live CD

Tags: networking, 16.04, hp, intel-wireless

I am trying to assess hardware issues in installing Ubuntu 16.04 desktop version on a HP x360 laptop with Intel Dual Band Wireless AC3165, before doing the actual install. When booted from live USB, wifi does not seem to work. The adapter has been reported to work with 15.10 at [How can I install Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672700/how-can-i-install-intel-dual-band-wireless-ac-3165-drivers), where the workaround suggests using iwlwifi driver for 7265D version 13-ucode. Further, https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi suggests that the wireless adapter should work directly with Linux kernel 4.1 onwards, as also [Wireless card firmware (Intel 3165 iwlwifi) only available for kernel 4.1+: any options for kernel 3.19?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713742/wireless-card-firmware-intel-3165-iwlwifi-only-available-for-kernel-4-1-any), which means it should work with 16.04. How should I get it working? My hardware info follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-21-generic

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -class network
      *-network DISABLED      
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Wireless 3165
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
           logical name: wlp2s0
           version: 81
           serial: dc:dc:dc:dc:dc:dc
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=16.242414.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
           resources: irq:294 memory:a1500000-a1501fff
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lspci -nn | grep -i wireless
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   17.217781] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.217813] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.217844] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.218368] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   17.308518] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   17.432981] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[   17.433316] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   17.433759] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   17.510413] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   17.511471] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   29.006838] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   29.007283] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   29.068127] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   29.068567] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  668.166467] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  668.166913] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  668.227723] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  668.228267] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  688.984299] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  688.984746] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  689.045996] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  689.046504] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/713742/wireless-card-firmware-intel-3165-iwlwifi-only-available-for-kernel-4-1-any#

Comment: Ah, well, yes, i have indeed reported that link in my question. However this and all other solutions require a reboot phase where the changes made in a LiveCD environment are unfortunately lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2306536

It worked on my HP Pavilion x360.